# CASE vs IF-ELSE-IF vs GOTO keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case, goto

I have some rules in my application and I have written the business logic of that rules in my procedure. At the time of creation of procedure I came to know that `CASE` expression won't work in my scenario. So I have tried two ways to perform same operations (using `IF-ELSE-IF` or `GOTO`) shown as below.

**Method 1 Using IF-ELSE-IF conditions:**

```
DECLARE @V_RuleId SMALLINT;

IF (@V_RuleId = 1) 
BEGIN 
    /*My business logic*/
END
ELSE IF (@V_RuleId = 2) 
BEGIN 
    /*My business logic*/
END
ELSE IF (@V_RuleId = 3) 
BEGIN 
    /*My business logic*/
END
/* 
...
...
...
...*/
ELSE IF (@V_RuleId = 19) 
BEGIN 
    /*My business logic*/
END
ELSE IF (@V_RuleId = 20) 
BEGIN 
    /*My business logic*/
END
```

**Method 2 Using GOTO statement:**

```
DECLARE @V_RuleId SMALLINT, @V_Temp VARCHAR(100);

SET @V_Temp = 'GOTO RULE' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @V_RuleId);
EXECUTE sp_executesql @V_Temp;

RULE1: 
BEGIN 
    /*My business logic*/
END

RULE2: 
BEGIN 
    /*My business logic*/
END

RULE3: 
BEGIN 
    /*My business logic*/
END

/* 
...
...
...
...*/

RULE19: 
BEGIN 
    /*My business logic*/
END

RULE20: 
BEGIN 
    /*My business logic*/
END
```

Today I have 20 rules. It can be increase to any number in future. If I can able to use CASE expression then I have not any problem with performance, but I can't do that so I am worried about the performance of my procedure.

Also one thing to be noticed that this procedure will execute very frequently by application.

**My question is:**

Is there any way to use CASE expression in my procedure? If not, which method is best to use in my procedure to improve the performance of my code?

Comment: Method 2 does not work..

Answer (score 3):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @V_RuleId SMALLINT
SELECT @V_RuleId = 1;

DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      RuleID INT
    , Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (RuleID, Query)
VALUES 
    (1, 'EXEC dbo.usp_test1;'),
    (2, 'CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1 (ID INT);'),
    (3, 'DROP TABLE dbo.Table1;')

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = Query 
FROM @temp
WHERE RuleID = @V_RuleId

PRINT @SQL

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not able to put my queries in table I have to put them in procedures for all rules.

Comment: As per requirement I have to put whole logic in one procedure i can't create multiple procedure for all rules.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, I don't think a `CASE` expression would work here. `CASE` will only return one value. I assume your procedure will return multiple values. I like your `GOTO` approach. You should try a couple thousand rules and see if performance is indeed an issue.

I also have another suggestion. You can put all your code in a table and run them as dynamic SQL. They won't be truly dynamic since they're always the same, so SQL Server can still cache those execution plans. Then the case lookup would be your table index, which is very fast. I am not sure if it's any faster than the `GOTO` approach though.

In conclusion, please try it with an absurd number of rules, and let us know what your results are.

Answer (score 0):

If I where you I would handle that logic in Domain layer (or Buisness layer in app) if that is possible. Because you will end up with problems in future if number of rules increases to large number (no one would be able to read that large SQL statement).

You should check Object Oriented SOLID Principles, especiall OpenClose principle.

Theoretically you could use case like this (depending of what rules are doing):

```
DECLARE @rule  int = 1;
SELECT CASE @rule
WHEN 1 THEN
@rule
WHEN 2 THEN 
@rule
END
```

But, because T-SQL is not a procedural language, maybe you should try to store that rules in tables and return rules from set instead of using procedural logic (for better performance) if that is possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but In our product we have requirement to do that logic in procedure, so I can't go for implementing at application level.

Comment: Hm,I expected that :),i will provide my second answer by editing original!